# How do I increase my internal Kubuntu partition size? (in dual boot with windows)

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, lts, memory-usage

My internal memory (I'm not good at English so i don't know exactly what we say it) is full for know.

Look at this image

[image]

This sentence is in my dolphin (Home folder)

How I can increase it?

I use Kubuntu 20.4 LTS

I have both Kubuntu and Windows.

Feel free to edit my question because I am sure it may have some spelling and writing problem's.

***Note***: [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) is not my answer because this is for v 12.4 and i use 20.4

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a screenshot of your partitions? Then it would be easier for someone to help you increase the partition size. You can install a software like https://apps.kde.org/en/partitionmanager to view all the partitions. You can install it either from Discover, or enter the command `sudo apt install partitionmanager` in a terminal. You may temporarilly uninstall a few large programs (e.g. email clients like thunderbird, if you don't use it), to free up some space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Actually, no because this question is about V 12.04 But I have 20.04 so I think it better I ask a question about the new version of Ubuntu